# My for-Loop isn't working as intended

Tags: python

I want to fill in the `list_of_occurences` with the correct item from the list `grundformen`.

My for-loop doesn't work as intended though. It doesn't restart from the beginning and only goes through the rows in the reader once.  Therefore it won't fill the list completely.

This is what it prints (you can see the part where something is missing - because it doesn't start searching from the beginning of the list - ):

```
# List_of_occurrences (1 line - wrapped for easier reading)
[['NN', 1328, ('Ziel',)], ['ART', 771, ('der',)], 
 ['$.', 732, ('_',)], ['VVFIN', 682, ('schlagen',)], 
 ['PPER', 592, ('sie',)], ['$,', 561, ('_',)], 
 ['ADV', 525, ('So',)], ['APPR', 507, ('in',)], 
 ['NE', 433, ('Johanna',)], ['$(', 363, ('_',)], 
 ['VAFIN', 334, ('haben',)], ['ADJA', 307, ('tragisch',)], 
 ['ADJD', 278, ('recht',)], ['KON', 228, ('Doch',)], 
 ['VVPP', 194, ('reichen',)], ['VVINF', 161, ('stören',)], 
 ['KOUS', 151, ('Während',)], ['PPOSAT', 120, ('ihr',)], 
 ['PTKVZ', 104, ('weiter',)], ['PRF', 98, ('sich',)], 
 ['APPRART', 90, ('zu',)], ['PTKNEG', 87, ('nicht',)], 
 ['VMFIN', 76, ('sollen',)], ['PIAT', 66, ('kein',)], 
 ['PIS', 65, ('etwas',)], ['PTKZU', 52, ('zu',)], 
 ['PRELS', 51, ('wer',)], ['PROAV', 42, ('dabei',)],  
 ['PDS', 38, ('jener',)], ['PDAT', 37, ('dieser',)], 
 ['PWAV', 30, ('wie',)], ['PWS', 26, ('Was',)], 
 ['CARD', 24, ('drei',)], ['KOKOM', 21, ('wie',)], 
 ['VAINF', 18, ('werden',)], ['KOUI', 15, ('um',)], 
 ['VMINF', 10, ('können',)], ['VVIZU', 10, ('aufklären',)], 
 ['VAPP', 10], ['PTKA', 6], ['PTKANT', 6], ['PWAT', 4], 
 ['VVIMP', 4], ['PRELAT', 4], ['APZR', 3], ['APPO', 2], 
 ['FM', 1]]

# Grundformen (1 line, wrapped for reading)
['Ziel', 'der', '_', 'schlagen', 'sie', '_', 'So', 'in', 'Johanna',
 '_', 'haben', 'tragisch', 'recht', 'Doch', 'reichen', 'stören', 
 'Während', 'ihr', 'weiter', 'sich', 'zu', 'nicht', 'sollen', 'kein', 
 'etwas', 'zu', 'wer', 'dabei', 'jener', 'dieser', 'wie', 'Was', 
 'drei', 'wie', 'werden', 'um', 'können', 'aufklären']
```

---

```
occurences = collections.Counter()

with open("material-2.csv", mode='r', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as material:
    reader = csv.reader(material, delimiter='\t', quotechar="\t")
    for line in reader:
        if line:
            occurences[line[5]] += 1
        else:
            pass

list_of_occurences = [list(elem) for elem in occurences.most_common()]

grundformen = []
with open('material-2.csv', mode='r', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as material:
    reader = csv.reader(material, delimiter='\t', quotechar="\t")
    for elem in list_of_occurences:
        for row in reader:
            if row != [] and row[5] == elem[0]:
                grundformen.append(row[2])
                break

iterator = 0
for elem in grundformen:
    list_of_occurences[iterator].insert(2, elem)
    iterator = iterator + 1
    pass

print(list_of_occurences)
print(grundformen)
```

---

whole inputfile: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xyktjk4ycm8x6v0/AACou438_eEWx-ZYmByBiqp_a/material-2.csv?dl=0

Part of my input file:

1   Als Als _   _   KOUS    _   _   6   6   CP  CP  _   _
2   es  es  _   _   PPER    _   3|Nom|Sg|Neut   6   6   SB  SB  _   _
3   zu  zu  _   _   PTKA    _   _   4   4   MO  MO  _   _
4   schneien    schneien    _   _   ADJD    _   Comp|Dat|Sg|Fem 5   5   MO  MO  _   _
5   aufgehört   aufhören    _   _   VVPP    _   Psp 6   6   OC  OC  _   _
6   hatte   haben   _   _   VAFIN   _   3|Sg|Past|Ind   8   8   MO  MO  _   _
7   ,   _   _   _   $,  _   _   8   8   PUNC    PUNC    _   _
8   verließ verlassen   _   _   VVFIN   _   3|Sg|Past|Ind   0   0   ROOT    ROOT    _   _
9   Johanna Johanna _   _   NE  _   Nom|Sg|Masc 8   8   SB  SB  _   _
10  von von _   _   APPR    _   _   5   5   SBP SBP _   _
11  Rotenhoff   Rotenhoff   _   _   NE  _   Dat|Sg|Neut 10  10  NK  NK  _   _
12  ,   _   _   _   $,  _   _   8   8   PUNC    PUNC    _   _
13  ohne    ohne    _   _   KOUI    _   _   18  18  CP  CP  _   _
14  ein ein _   _   ART _   Nom|Sg|Neut 16  16  NK  NK  _   _
15  rechtes recht   _   _   ADJA    _   Pos|Nom|Sg|Neut 16  16  NK  NK  _   _
16  Ziel    Ziel    _   _   NN  _   Nom|Sg|Neut 18  18  OA  OA  _   _
17  zu  zu  _   _   PTKZU   _   _   18  18  PM  PM  _   _
18  haben   haben   _   _   VAINF   _   Inf 8   8   MO  MO  _   _
19  ,   _   _   _   $,  _   _   18  18  PUNC    PUNC    _   _
20  das der _   _   ART _   Nom|Sg|Neut 21  21  NK  NK  _   _
21  Gutshaus    Gutshaus    _   _   NN  _   Nom|Sg|Neut 16  16  APP APP _   _
22  .   _   _   _   $.  _   _   8   8   PUNC    PUNC    _   _

how can I change my loop, so that it can fill in everything?

Comment: What results were you expecting?

Comment: As you can see in my 2 lists in the beginning, it stops filling in words after:['VVIZU', 10, ('aufklären',)],                                                         This is left blank:                                                                           ['VAPP', 10], ['PTKA', 6], ['PTKANT', 6], ['PWAT', 4], ['VVIMP', 4], ['PRELAT', 4], ['APZR', 3], ['APPO', 2], ['FM', 1]]                                       Which tells my for-loop only works until a certain point and doesn't restart again to get the missing words (which then, would be filled in the gaps)

Comment: I want every speech tag in the list_of_occurences to be compared  to the speechtag in every line of the reader. If both of them match, I want the string row[2]  to be appended into the "grundformen"list. To do this I wrote a for loop which iterates through the list_of_occurences and a nested one which iterates through every row until they match. I only want one example word for each Part-Of-Speech-Tag thats why i used break, but it causes the loop not do start again from the beginning resulting in not finding an example word for the last few speech tags

Comment: Does your second list `['Ziel', 'der', '_', ...]` contain the expected output? Could you provide a link to your actual input file?

Comment: No it doesn't, as it loops through the text just once, matching everything in one loop instead of beginning at the start of the text as soon as one match is found. 'der' should be 'ein' because it would be the first article if it had started from the beginning

Comment: This is a link to the file: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xyktjk4ycm8x6v0/AAAUIDTxdzJvRs4gJmbp4IDna?dl=0

Comment: I don't know if you still need it but, i made a slightly more efficient version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had an issue with how you were reading in your `csv` data.

Here the data is read into a `list` and can be gone through for the second loop instead of opening another `file-object` but you don't even need to loop through the `csv` data twice:

```
import csv
import collections

occurences = collections.Counter()
grundformen = collections.defaultdict(list)

with open("material-2.csv", mode='r', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as material:
    reader = [ln for ln in csv.reader(material, delimiter='\t', quotechar="\t") if ln]
    for line in reader:
        occurences[line[5]] += 1
        grundformen[line[5]].append(line[2])
    list_of_occurences = list(map(list, occurences.most_common()))
    for elem in list_of_occurences:
        elem.append(grundformen[elem[0]][0])

print(occurences)
```

By making a `list` out of your `csv` data, you are able to call the `break` statement and still be able to start a fresh at the head of the `list` for your next loop.  When you loop over the [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) this is an `iterator` so even when calling `break` you will start where you left off until its data is exhausted.

Answer (score 1):

```
reader = csv.reader(material, delimiter='\t', quotechar="\t")
```

Setting the quotechar the same as the delimiter looks rather strange. The CSV reader will probably get confused, and take either all tabs (`\t`) as delimiters, or interpret them all as quotechars.

Comment: Changing this or deleting the delimiter gives me following error:                                                                                                                if row != [] and row[5] == elem[0]:
    IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Can you show us (edit you question or provide a link) to an input file (material-2.csv)? If too long, maybe an excerpt of the file? I have the impression that the problem is the reading of the file.